# Why is a captureless lambda always true when converted to bool, and why is this not the case for a lambda with captures?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Consider a function to compare positive integers; the function itself uses a lambda to do the job ..

```
// Pass n1, n2 by value to the lambda.
bool Compare(int n1, int n2) {
    return [](int n1, int n2) { return n1 > n2; };
}
```

The above snippet compiles fine; though Compare() always returns true;

However, the following code even fails to compile -

```
// capturing values
bool Compare(int n1, int n2) {
    return [n1, n2]() -> bool { return n1 > n2; };
}
```

and returns the error

```
lambda.cpp:48:46: error: cannot convert 'Compare(int, int)::__lambda2' to 'bool' in   return
  return [n1, n2]() -> bool { return n1 > n2; };
```

**Question**

May be these are not the intended use of introducing lambda's in C++, still...

1. Why the first one always returns true?
2. Why second fails to compile?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Why the first one always returns true?

Lambdas decay into function pointers, which are implicitly convertible to booleans (always `true` for lambdas because the pointer is never null).

> Why second fails to compile?

Lambdas that capture anything do not have this conversion to a function pointer (how would that state get through?)

**If you must use a lambda:**

Call it:

```
return [](int n1, int n2) { return n1 > n2; }(n1, n2); //notice the () to call it
```

Or, your second way, which makes more sense, but not as much as just `return n1 > n2`:

```
return [=] { return n1 > n2; }(); //= captures everything used by value
                                  //-> bool and parameter list are redundant
```

Finally, it's worth noting that `std::greater`, in `<functional>`, already does this:

```
std::sort(…, std::greater<int>()); //std::greater<> in C++14
```

Comment: For completeness, it's worth adding how to correctly use the second one.